# Reproducing sinusoid with autoregressive discrete model

Tags: time-series, self-study, autoregressive

I wonder how to reproduce sinusoid with autogressive discrete model :
`y = sin(t)` with or without additive noise is my target, `t` here is continuous variable. `sin(t)` could be expanded with Taylor expension, but I'm looking for autogressive formulation : `y[t] = a1*y[t-1] + a2*y[t-2]+...`, 
I could create artificial data, choose number of lags then fit model on these data, but how to control over number of realisation of this process in one cycle ? For example, below, there are 8 realisations per cycle of sinusoid which period is 0.1 sec

[image]

Comment: just a question... why?

Comment: @carlo I would like to model if two time series diverse from each other by following sinusoidal pattern, I don't know if making linear regression and then ARMA on its residuals will be the correct procedure (unbiased, with low variance) so I try to understand modeling sinusoid from the scratch its also useful for generation additional realizations of observed signal

Comment: You can fit an autoregressive model with exogenous regressors to your data; then, compare the series by checking the roots and associated cycles of the AR model.

Answer (score 6):

You can prove that the coefficients of a **AR(2)** model without added noise can reproduce a sine wave.

You can write your AR model as:

```
x(n+1) = a1*x(n) + a2*x(n-1)
```

Setting `x(n+1)` as the predicted sine wave, you get:

```
sin(2pi*f*(n+1)) = a1*sin(2pi*f*n) + a2*sin(2pi*f*(n-1))
```

Knowing that `sin(a+b) + sin(a-b) = 2cos(b)sin(a)` you can rearrange your equation: (with `a = 2pi*f*n, b = 2pi*f`)

```
sin(2pi*f*n + 2pi*f)) - a2*sin(2pi*f*n - 2pi*f) = a1*sin(2pi*f*n)
```

You find out that:

```
a1 = 2cos(2pi*f)
a2 = -1
```