# Mysterious: linear model perfectly predicts sine waves forever ONLY when not in phase!

Tags: correlation, forecasting, predictive-models, multivariate-analysis, linear-model

***Overview***

I am working with a very simple linear prediction model, and I am testing its limits using a basic example featuring two sine waves. I am **shocked** at how well the model is performing, and I would like to gain some insight as to how this could be.

The problem is as follows.

***Training***

There are two sine wave functions, $f_1[n] = \sin({2\pi \nu n - \phi_1})$ and $f_2[n] = \sin({2\pi \nu n - \phi_2})$, which differ only in their phase offsets $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, respectively. Note that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are scalars, that $\nu$ is the constant frequency of the sine waves, and that $n$ is an integer.

Let $\mathbf{X}_1$ and $\mathbf{X}_2$ be column vectors of sequential samples of $f_1[n]$ and $f_2[n]$, respectively. Similarly, let $\mathbf{Y}_1$ and $\mathbf{Y}_2$ be column vectors of sequential samples of $f_1[n+1]$ and $f_2[n+1]$, respectively. In other words, $\mathbf{Y}_1$ is one step ahead of $\mathbf{X}_1$, and $\mathbf{Y}_2$ is one step ahead of $\mathbf{X}_2$.

Let's define $\mathbf{X} = [\mathbf{X}_1 \  \mathbf{X}_2]$ and $\mathbf{Y} = [\mathbf{Y}_1 \  \mathbf{Y}_2]$ for ease of notation.

As per multivariate linear least-squares regression, we seek the linear transformation matrix $\mathbf{V}$ that minimizes the square error between $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$. As is known, the solution is $\mathbf{V} = (\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{Y} $.

Here is corresponding MATLAB code:

```
phi1 = 0;
phi2 = pi/10;
X1 = sin( 2*pi*0.08*(0:999) - phi1 )';
X2 = sin( 2*pi*0.08*(0:999) - phi2 )';
X = [X1 X2];
Y1 = sin( 2*pi*0.08*(1:1000) - phi1 )';
Y2 = sin( 2*pi*0.08*(1:1000) - phi2 )';
Y = [Y1 Y2];
V = pinv(X'*X)*X'*Y;
```

Here is corresponding Python code:

```
import numpy as np
phi1 = 0
phi2 = np.pi/10
X1 = np.sin( 2*np.pi*0.08*np.arange(0,1000) - phi1 )
X2 = np.sin( 2*np.pi*0.08*np.arange(0,1000) - phi2 )
X = np.stack( ( X1 , X2 ) ).transpose()
Y1 = np.sin( 2*np.pi*0.08*np.arange(1,1001) - phi1 )
Y2 = np.sin( 2*np.pi*0.08*np.arange(1,1001) - phi2 )
Y = np.stack( ( Y1 , Y2 ) ).transpose()
V = np.matmul( np.linalg.pinv( np.matmul(X.transpose(),X) ) , np.matmul(X.transpose() , Y) )
```

***Testing***

Now that we have the best linear mapping between (1) an interval of these two sine waves and (2) an interval of these waves one step ahead, we test how well this model predicts the next step in general by recursively feeding the prediction and comparing to the ground truth.

For instance, let $m$ be a time step following the training interval, and let $\tilde{f}_1[m]$ and $\tilde{f}_2[m]$ be the predicted values of $f_1[m]$ and $f_2[m]$, respectively. Thus, $[\tilde{f}_1[m+1] \ \tilde{f}_2[m+1] ] = [\tilde{f}_1[m] \ \tilde{f}_2[m] ] \mathbf{V} $ defines the recurrence relation of the testing phase.

Below is the corresponding MATLAB code.

```
tmp = X(end,:)*V;
predicted = [];
ground_truth = [sin( 2*pi*0.08*(1001:2000) - phi1 )' sin( 2*pi*0.08*(1001:2000) - phi2 )'];
for ii = 1 : 1000
    tmp = tmp*V;
    predicted = [predicted; tmp];
end
```

And here is the code in Python:

```
tmp = np.dot( X[-1] , V )
predicted = np.empty((1000,2))
ground_truth = np.stack(( np.sin( 2*np.pi*0.08*np.arange(1001,2001) - phi1 ) , np.sin( 2*np.pi*0.08*np.arange(1001,2001) - phi2 ) )).transpose()
for ii in range(1000):
    tmp = np.dot(tmp,V)
    predicted[ii] = tmp
```

***Results***

As the title of this post suggests, the prediction is nearly perfect during testing. Below are the predicted sines when $\phi_2 - \phi_1 = \pi/10$:

[image: plotsines]

Furthermore, it performs this well for all phase differences EXCEPT for when $\phi_2 - \phi_1 = 0$ or $2\pi$ (*i.e.*, when the two sines are identical):

[image: mse]

For the cases where performance is poor (*i.e.*, zero phase difference--identical sines), the prediction tends to zero--the mean value:

[image: plotsines-zero]

***Closing remarks***

Thanks for reading! I hope you find this result as curious as I do, and I'm looking forward to learning how this unintuitive result is possible!

Comment: Without noise, predictions are easy to make perfect! Add some noise to the two sinewaves, and you'll see that the prediction is no longer perfect. For instance, you can add a white gaussian noise to the vectors $\mathbf{X}_1$ and $\mathbf{X}_2$, or you can add some frequency or phase noise to the arguments of the sine functions.

Comment: Try trig identity; sine of sum of two angles.

Comment: This is trig, i.e., Math not stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a $2\times 2$ matrix that gives  the values of two sinusoids of the same frequency from their lagged values, so it is not strange that you obtain such a good fit.

When the two sinusoids are the same (phase difference equal to zero), you lose that ability to reconstruct them from lagged values. Intuitively, from a single sinusoide you cannot anticipate the "next" value, for a single value can be followed by two different ones (depending on whether the function is ascending or descending).

Comment: Thanks--that makes sense to me. When the two input sines' phases are different, it seems the model is autoregressive. Specifically, it seems the 2x2 matrix gives two AR(2) models--one for each output sine. Apparently it is possible to perfectly predict a sine wave with an AR(2) model (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268426/reproducing-sinusoid-with-autoregressive-discrete-model). If no one can find any issues with what has been said, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @the-one-who-knocks, yes. In fact, the 2x2 matrix needs not be estimated, it can be constructed from simple trigonometric relations. This is quite common in state-space models to account for seasonality.